# Set blendmodes on UIImageViews like Photoshop

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

I've been trying to apply blend modes to my UIImageViews to replicate a PSD mock up file (sorry can't provide). The PSD file has 3 layers, a base color with 60% normal blend, an image layer with 55% multiply blend and a gradient layer with 35% overlay.

I've been trying several tutorials over the internet but still could not get the colors/image to be exactly the same.

One thing I noticed is that the color of my iPhone is different from my Mac's screen.

I found the documentation for Quartz 2D which I think is the right way to go, but I could not get any sample/tutorial about Using Blend Modes with Images.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBIJEFG

Can anyone provide a good tutorial that does the same as the one in the documentation so I could atleast try to mix things up should nobody provide me a straight forward answer to my question.

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked ages ago, but if someone is looking for the same anwser, you can user `compositingFilter` on the backing layer of your view to get what you want:

```
overlayView.layer.compositingFilter = "multiplyBlendMode"
```

Suggested by @SeanA, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46676507/1147286

**Filters**
Complete list of filters is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW71)
Or you can print out the compositing filter types with

```
print("Filters:\n",CIFilter.filterNames(inCategory: kCICategoryCompositeOperation))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Now built-in to iOS. Historic answer:*

You don't want to use UIImageView for this since it doesn't really support blend modes.

Instead, the way to go would be to create a UIView subclass (which will act just like UIImageView). So make a UIView subclass called something like BlendedImageView. It should have an image property, and then in the drawRect: method you can do this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //
    // Here you need to calculate a rect based on self.contentMode to replicate UIImageView-behaviour.
    // For example, for UIViewContentModeCenter, you want a rect that goes outside 'rect' and centers with it.
    //
    CGRect actualRect = // ...
    [self.image drawInRect:actualRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:0.5];
}
```

Replace alpha and blend mode to fit your preference. Good practice would be to let your BlendedImageView save a blendMode property.

It may be that in your case, you need to do a bit more advanced view that draws all 3 of your images, using the same code as above.

Comment: Do you think doing like 3 views and putting them on top of each other will do?

Comment: I'm not sure. It will work as long as a drawInRect: blends with other views than itself. If not, it's not very hard to just draw the three views

Comment: I have just tried this for multiple UIImageViews overlaying each other, it doesn't seem to work :( Does anybody know of other solutions?

Comment: Friends, the other extremely old, OOD answers here have been deleted.  I've politely added a "historic answer..." tag. Obviously edit as you please cheers!