# iPhone status bar items automatically swap dark/light per the background - how to use this ability on a symbol?

Tags: ios, swift, ios17

The items in the status bar now work like this on an iPhone:

[image]

(The white bar moving up and down is just a square of white I put in a scroll view.)

The SF symbols know to change from light/dark depending on the background.

Here's a symbol I added to a button.

It does not have the automatic light/dark behavior.

[image]

Is there a way to get the same effect on my own button or SF symbol using something Apple provides?

(Please note that I know how to tediously program this manually on my own. I'm wondering if we have access to the same calls Apple does? Apple has so many systems now it's impossible to find or know them all!)

One thought I had was, could I make a status bar item (or something like that) but actually not place it on the status bar?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with SF Symbols. The status bar changes the clock text color as well as various symbols, all based on whatever color happens to be behind the status bar. I don't think any public API in UIKit lets you automatically adjust something's color based on the color of whatever happens to be behind it at the moment.

Comment: Quite right - it does the numbers also.  It looks like unfortunately there's no immediate way to do this, as, nobody has answered yet!  Doh!  A shame ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get quite close to the same effect if you use `Color.white` as foreground color and then apply either `BlendMode.exclusion` or `BlendMode.difference`.

- For black and white backgrounds, this works the same as the native symbols in the iOS header.
- For colored backgrounds, you get the inverted color. If you know the background will be colored then `BlendMode.colorDodge` might be a better choice.

Like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color.white
                .frame(height: 200)
            Color.black
                .frame(height: 200)
            Color.blue
                .frame(height: 200)
            Color.red
                .frame(height: 200)
            Color.yellow
                .frame(height: 200)
            Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
                .frame(height: 1000)
        }
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
        Image(systemName: "xmark")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            .padding(.top, 80)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .blendMode(.exclusion)
//            .blendMode(.difference) // works same as .exclusion
//            .blendMode(.colorDodge) // for colored backgrounds
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Duh, of course!!!!!!!  Absolutely brilliant, thank you so much !!!!!!! Didn't think of blend mode at all. Brilliant, TY

Comment: @Fattie Pleased to hear you approve! Documentation for the different types of ```BlendMode``` is, shall we say, hard to find, so I just ended up trying them all out. I was hoping it might be possible to combine modes (to add more brightness to the colored variations) but unfortunately I couldn't find a way of doing that.

Comment: Right. I'm surely familiar with blend mode'ing but it just didn't occur to me!!! Genius!! TY !!! Other useful links for googlers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55183805/294884

Comment: For anyone looking for a UIKit solution, please see [How to get multiply blend mode on a plain UIView (not UIImage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407396/how-to-get-multiply-blend-mode-on-a-plain-uiview-not-uiimage).