# merge two CAShaplayer with transparent in Swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, swift5

We have created two **CAShapeLayer** and we have animated them by **CABasicAnimation** changing **position** like **fromValue** to **toValue** so far code works as excepted.

Two **layers** meeting at some **points** while animating, its moving one over another seems overlapping. We need to achieve like below image but we have got different output.

Desired output:

[image: Actual Output]

Output at Loading view::

[image: View Load]

Result we got after animating layers:

[image: Result]

**Code Below:**

```
class MovingAnimationVC: UIViewController {

    let layerSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    
    private var layerWidth : CGFloat = 100
    private var layerHeight : CGFloat = 100
    
    var circleA : CAShapeLayer! = nil
    var circleB : CAShapeLayer! = nil
    
    lazy var aPosition = CGPoint(x: -layerWidth/2 + 30, y: 100)
    lazy var bPosition = CGPoint(x: (self.view.frame.width - layerWidth / 2) - 30 , y: 400)
    
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if circleA == nil{
            circleA = CAShapeLayer()
            let pa = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: aPosition, size: layerSize))
            circleA.path = pa.cgPath
            circleA.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
            view.layer.addSublayer(circleA)
        }
        if circleB == nil{
            circleB = CAShapeLayer()
            let pa = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: bPosition, size: layerSize))
            circleB.path = pa.cgPath
            circleB.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
            view.layer.addSublayer(circleB)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        animateCircleA()
        animateCircleB()
    }
    fileprivate func animateCircleA(){
        lazy var startPointA = CGPoint(x: -layerWidth/2 + 30, y: 0)
        lazy var endPointA = CGPoint(x: (self.view.frame.width - layerWidth / 2), y: 300)
        
       
        let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animate.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
        animate.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: startPointA)
        animate.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: endPointA)
        animate.repeatCount = 2
        animate.duration = 5.0
        circleA.add(animate, forKey: "position")
    }
    fileprivate func animateCircleB(){
        
        lazy var startPointB = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        lazy var endPointB = CGPoint(x:-(self.view.frame.width - layerWidth / 2) - 30, y: -(self.view.frame.width - layerWidth / 2) + 30)
        
        let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animate.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
        animate.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: startPointB)
        animate.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: endPointB)
        animate.repeatCount = 2
        animate.duration = 5.0
        circleB.add(animate, forKey: "position")
    }

}
```

Kindly suggest me right way to get started.

How to make both layer transparent while crossing each other?

Comment: its not overlapping if we set alpha or opacity but we need alpha 1 at viewload.

Comment: Is there any possibility of tracking animations?

Comment: Can you guide me to achieve this?

Comment: yes if its helps, direct support not there as you said there is no easy way to do this

Comment: Actually I found a better way, so please ignore what I said before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just set the `alpha`s of the layers, but if you don't want the layers to be transparent, then that means you want a different *blend mode* for the layers.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407396/how-to-get-multiply-blend-mode-on-a-plain-uiview-not-uiimage), to change the blend mode of a layer, you can set `CALayer.compositingFilter`. From your desired output, it seems like the screen blend mode is appropriate:

```
circleA.compositingFilter = "screenBlendMode"
circleA.compositingFilter = "screenBlendMode"
```

[image]

Note that you should add your layers to a view with a transparent background, otherwise the background color of the view is also blended with the circles' colours. This view can be added as a subview of whatever view you were originally going to put the circles in, filling its entire bounds.

```
someView.backgroundColor = .clear
someView.layer.addSublayer(circleA)
someView.layer.addSublayer(circleB)
```